# Execute Shared Libary From FreeStyle Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, groovyshell

I have a shared library repository that contains all of my shared functions.

Is it possible to somehow use this within a freestyle job?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a freestyle job that calls and executes code from the vars folder of my shared library repository.

Is this possible at all?

Freestyle jobs have a **Execute Groovy Script** Build Step and I wonder if it might be possible to write a groovy script that calls a function within a global shared library.

I've tried to call the function using

```
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell()
def tools = shell.parse(new File('demoFree.groovy'))
tools.call()
```

`demoFree.groovy` being the name of the file that holds the function but my Groovy knowledge is very limited so I'm probably doing something very wrong.

I know this is easily done using a pipeline project but I'm having to deal with a legacy freestyle project which for a number of reasons isn't being moved to a declarative pipeline just yet.

Comment: It's really depends on what you have in `demoFree.groovy`. if you are not using pipeline steps inside then your code could work. Otherwise - almost impossible.

Answer (score 2):

No. According to the [Documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) shared libraries are meant to be executed only from Jenkins pipelines.

However, you can easily create a pipeline job, choose **Pipeline Script** (instead of Pipeline from SCM) and write the code you need that uses your library.

You will find it much more convenient that using a FreeStyle job.

Comment: I've updated the question, but yeah! You might have a point. 
I was just wondering if it might be possible to use the Execute Groovy Script build step to call the function, but I don't know if this is a thing at all

Comment: You will need to have some kind of custom SCM mechanism to first retrieve the shared library code, and only then you will be able to load it.
In pipeline jobs Jenkins does it for you

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll look at implementing a custom mechanism of sorts.